# What is this plant in my succulent?

Tags: identification, succulents, weeds

I recently bought this plant and was wondering whether this was a weed or whether I need to cut this back over time? Thanks [image]

Comment: Is it the flower?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your plant is producing a flower  - let it do its thing, then remove  the flowered stem once flowering is finished.